# Python gzip - extracting .csv.gz file - memory error

Tags: python, memory, gzip, extract, memory-efficient

I tried to write a script to access a .csv.gz file from a ftp server and write the contents to a .csv file back on the same server. This method seems to work fine as long as the file is less than 100mb, over that it fails, giving a memory error. I wasn't able to find a way to just extract the .csv file so it reads the file content (a list of tuples) line by line and writes that to a new file.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, or even a way to just extract the .csv file directly from the .csv.gz file?

```
def gz_unzipper():

    hostname = "servername"
    directory = "path"
    input_file = directory + "filename.csv.gz"
    output_file = directory + "filename.csv"
    ftp = FTP(hostname)
    ftp.login (username, password)
    ftp.cwd(directory)

    f = gzip.open(input_file, 'r')
    gz_content = f.read()

    lines=csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(gz_content))

    output_file = open(output_file, 'w')

    for line in lines:
        line  = repr(line)[1:-1]
        line = line.replace("'","")
        line = line.replace(" ","")

        output_file.write(line + "\n") 

    output_file.close  
    f.close()
```

Comment: Could you add a stack trace (the python output) of where it hits the MemoryError?

Comment: @Super Nova Was my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are reading in the whole file at once, which is fine for small files but (obviously) causes problems if you have a lot of data. Since you are dealing with the file line-by-line, you can use the built-in Python iterators for files/csvfiles. These are typically implemented as *lazy*, meaning they only read in data when they need it.

Try something like this (sorry, untested):

```
with gzip.open(input_file, 'r') as fin, open(output_file,'w') as fout:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fin)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_writer.writerows(csv_reader)
```